# PyMC3 dependencies between series elements

Tags: pymc

I want a model that includes dependencies between elements of time series. Let say we have 4 years of hourly data, with features *X* and labels *y*.

I want to include an assumption "slightly similar to day before and hour before" this way:

```
y_i ~ d1 * A * X + d2 * y_(i-1) + d3 * y_(i-24)

d1 + d2 + d3 == 1
```

- Is it possible in pymc3? preferably without python loop over data, but if it is the only way, let it be.
- Maybe there is a way to reformulate this and get similar result?
- Is it a good task for pymc3 anyway?

Comment: Yes, this is certainly possible. Essentially this is an autoregressive model, you can look at the AR1 distribution for some inspirations of how to do that without a loop: https://github.com/pymc-devs/pymc3/blob/master/pymc3/distributions/timeseries.py#L29